# Dismissal Issues in UIPopOverViewControler

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, uipopovercontroller

I am having a `popovercontroller` to dispay a search page ,it shows the search page nicly,when the user tap the cell inside the popover it will show the corresponding page inside the `popovercontroller`,I dont want it,so I put the `NSNotification` for displaying the `popover`,and it works fine,but I got a problem that ,but navigation is not happen there in `popovercontroller` ,only dismissal happen.
this is my code to create a popover

```
-(void)revealRightSidebar:(id)sender
{
    searchpage* popoverContent = [[searchpage alloc]
                                  init];    
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:popoverContent] autorelease];

    //resize the popover view shown
    //in the current view to the view's size
    popoverContent.contentSizeForViewInPopover =
    CGSizeMake(320,650);

    //create a popover controller
    self.popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc]
                              initWithContentViewController:navigationController];

    [self.popup presentPopoverFromRect:_btnsearch.frame
                                            inView:self.view
                          permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny
                                          animated:YES];

    //release the popover content

    [popoverContent release];    

    [self resetReadViewToVerse:1];
}
```

in `viewDidLoad` method of this page i put the notification

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(dismissThePopover) name:@"popoverShouldDismiss" object:nil];
}
```

in searchpage i put this code to navigate to the corresponding search result page

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{          
     ParallelReadViewController *detailViewController = [[ParallelReadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParallelReadViewController" bundle:nil];

     //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

     [detailViewController release];   
     delegate.selectedBook = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"book"];
     delegate.selectedChapter = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"chapter"];
     delegate.selectedVerse = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"verse"];
     [delegate reloadVerses];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"popoverShouldDismiss" object:nil];
}
```

but when I remove the notification it navigate to the correspondent search in `parallelReadViewController` page ,but within the `popover` itself,here the `popover` dismiss,but no navigation.please help me to do this.

Comment: @Atulkumar V.Jain any help from ur side?

Answer (score 0):

You must be having a `navigationController` declared inside the `AppDelegate` class. Use that `navigationController` for pushing the required view.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{                 
    ParallelReadViewController *detailViewController = [[ParallelReadViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ParallelReadViewController" bundle:nil];         
   //detailViewController.firstString = firstString;       
   // ...   
   // Pass the selected object to the new view controller. 
   [delegate.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];          
   [detailViewController release];
   delegate.selectedBook = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"book"];
   delegate.selectedChapter = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"chapter"];
   delegate.selectedVerse = [[searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"verse"];
   [delegate reloadVerses];
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"popoverShouldDismiss" object:nil];
}
```

Hope this might help you.......